# filter the list for start date and end date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have to filter a list depending on the start date and end date. The NSDate extension is as follows,

```
public func <(a: NSDate, b: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return a.compare(b) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}

public func ==(a: NSDate, b: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return a.compare(b) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
}

extension NSDate:Comparable{}
```

the list is as follows,

```
class  Observation
{
  var date:NSDate = NSDate()
  var value:String = ""
}

var observationList = [Observation]()
```

now i am filtering like this,

```
let filterObservations = observationList.filter( { return $0.date >= startDate && $0.date < endDate} )
```

but it is not returning anything. Can anyone please point me what i did wrong. my observationList has definitely got an item lying in start date and end date range.

Thanks,
neena

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. The problem may be at `startDate` and `endDate`. Can you show more code?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine on a playground.

Comment: @neena if you want to do atemporal comparison for a specific date you need to use NSCalendar method isDate(inSameDayAsDate:) or just use startOfDay of your startDate and for your endDate use startOfDay of the next day

Comment: Hi, I have figured out the problem the problem was with the startdate and end date . it was trying to compare with even time component. I have removed the time component from the start date and end date.